# Stop Drop-down animation on RollOver

Tags: jquery, animation, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a drop down menu that have a roll over effect.

When the user rolls over an item in the 1st menu level I want to STOP all the drop-down animation still ruing in All the other menu items. 
But I cannot find the way to apply this simple code in all that mess.

There are 3 solutions to this problem:

1. Literary just close all drop down without animation.
2. Close with animation.
3. or Stop the animation

The 2 solution would be great. When I rollover an item close all other drop-down with animation. Right now any of the solutions work for me.

**UPDATE:**

My final result was:

```
$('.dropdown:animated').not(this).not('.selected').stop().hide();
```

Comment: Here is the drop down menu: http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/xGD6B/3/

Comment: Here is the possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/qZUsE/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$(':animated').stop();
```

This just stops all animations that are currently active. It does not however close the open menuitems.

If you want to close the open items I sugest you look at how the menuitems are normally closed and apply that to the wrapped set. For instance: this could work:

```
$(':animated').stop().hide();
```

Comment: Please apply it here, becouse I cant: http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/xGD6B/3/

Comment: I see. I will try it. But if there is a way of closing let me know. Thanks. I can't vote yet. Dam!

Comment: good to hear. Please mark my answer as the correct one if it helped you. Cheers.